# Electrical circuit / transformer in series?

Tags: ac, transformer, electromagnetism, ac-dc

I would like to pull out 5v 3A max in series from an already existing connection from the mains 240v 40A connection.

Current circuit:

[image: www.tryit.sg/electrical/mains1.jpg]

What I would like to implement:

[image: www.tryit.sg/electrical/mains2.jpg]

What are the possible problems with this setup? What device should I use to pull out the electricity? If possible I want to retain a 240v across the load.

Comment: What do I click for "scary schematic!?"

Comment: I'm wondering about the same thing, does this have a name? I need to extract under 50mA from such a circuit, note, in my case I absolutely have no other option, so please do not start talking about risks and start talking like an engineer, thanks

Answer (score 5):

Possible problems? Like it's a big old fire hazard, or won't work?

Don't connect anything in series with a 240 V load that isn't a power switch. It doesn't work like you think it does.

What you need is a transformer that connects in *parallel* to the 240 V, preferably by plugging it into its own outlet, and steps that down to around 6-9 V, which you can rectify, filter, and regulate down to 5 V. Which is what pretty much what an off-the-shelf 5 V wall wart does right now... so you may as well buy one of those.

Comment: +1 for "...so you may as well buy one of those." Very well said.

Comment: I'm working on a project myself where I don't have any other options, I have the hot, the load, and the earth ground. I need 50mA, my only options is the hot and the load, in series with the load, this is for a home automation project

Comment: There's always another option from creating a fire hazard. In any case, don't send a current through an earth ground, and any voltage you take from the load is going to affect the load. If you're lucky, the load has a switching power supply on the secondary side of the transformer that has a wide input voltage range, and the transformer's wires are beefy enough to handle the increased current (current goes up when voltage goes down, to deliver the same power to a switcher) without heating up enough to scorch nearby materials. If you're lucky.

Answer (score 4):

The proposed circuit will not work as visualized: The voltage across the primary coil of the transformer will vary depending upon the effective instantaneous impedance of the existing load. Thus, the voltage across the secondary will also vary.

While this may be the actual intent of the question, i.e. a method to generate a variable DC output depending on the current drawn by the existing load, this too will not work as such: The voltage across the load will not be 220 Volts any more, but will vary depending on the ratio of impedance of the load and the transformer.

Instead, consider using a transformer in parallel with the load, if it must be on the same line, as proposed in another answer.

Comment: is there a way to calculate the voltage drop considering that the resistance of the load might not be fixed?

Comment: @IonTodirel Firstly, with an AC source, resistance alone doesn't tell the whole story: The AC impedance of the load will need to be known. Beyond that, no, without knowing the load impedance, there is no  way of analytically determining the voltage drop - Empirically, sure: Just stick a voltmeter in there.

Comment: is there a way to design for a range of loads? the voltage drops is only a small factor, what if I know I need to extract 50mA?

Comment: @IonTodirel Use a transformer or a capacitive-drop in parallel with the load, as already stated in the answer.

Comment: that is not an option, I do not have the neutral

Comment: @IonTodirel Please think for a moment why it won't work.